# why Change the status of Mysql to Failed every few hours

Tags: mysql, linux, server, buffer

Mysql status fails every few hours, I also checked the buffer size, no problem with them and
The following message is displayed with the below command:

> systemctl status mysqld

```
● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Wed 2020-12-02 17:05:42 EST; 8h ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 25565 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 25543 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 17582 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

Dec 02 17:05:42 test.local systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
Dec 02 17:05:42 test.local systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
Dec 02 17:05:42 test.local systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
Dec 02 17:05:42 test.local systemd[1]: mysqld.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 02 17:05:42 test.local systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Server.
Dec 02 17:05:42 test.local systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for mysqld.service
Dec 02 17:05:42 test.local systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.
Dec 02 17:05:42 test.local systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.
Dec 02 17:05:42 test.local systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
```

I also checked the log file and the following event occurred:

```
2020-12-02T22:05:42.179677Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation $2020-12-02T22:05:42.184072Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.31) starting as process 25570 ...
2020-12-02T22:05:42.204497Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
2020-12-02T22:05:42.204557Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-12-02T22:05:42.204565Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-12-02T22:05:42.204574Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-12-02T22:05:42.204579Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-12-02T22:05:42.204584Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2020-12-02T22:05:42.204998Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-12-02T22:05:42.205184Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-12-02T22:05:42.208098Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 6G, instances = 8, chunk size = 128M
2020-12-02T22:05:42.443914Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: mmap(137428992 bytes) failed; errno 12
2020-12-02T22:05:42.510301Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
2020-12-02T22:05:42.510359Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
2020-12-02T22:05:42.510376Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2020-12-02T22:05:42.510384Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
2020-12-02T22:05:42.510391Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
2020-12-02T22:05:42.510399Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

2020-12-02T22:05:42.510438Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
2020-12-02T22:05:42.510525Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2020-12-02T22:05:42.511922Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

---

also My.cf file:

```
[mysqld]
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock



symbolic-links=0
innodb_file_per_table = 1
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 1024K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 1024K
sort_buffer_size = 1024K
table_open_cache = 64
max_allowed_packet = 2M
key_buffer_size = 64M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 6024M



log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

I tested this project on a server with 2 GB of RAM, but it failed on a server with 8 GB of RAM.

Comment: `perror 12` ->  `OS error code  12:  Cannot allocate memory`. You have run out of memory. Tune your allocations down or install more memory.

Comment: I tested this project on a server with 2 GB of RAM, but it failed on a server with 8 GB of RAM.

Comment: That isn't necessary inconsistent without out of memory. Probably because on your test server you didn't use all of the allocated buffer pool. Generally in linux you can allocate more memory than you actually have. A few hours of production use does however use it at which point the oom kills your process (check `dmesg`).

Answer (score 0):

Consider these changes to your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G
```

and  REMOVE to allow defaults to work for improved performance

```
read_rnd_buffer_size
read_buffer_size
sort_buffer_size
```

to reduce RAM footprint.

For additional suggestions, view my profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.

Comment: @samad When you have enough reputation points, if any of the comments or Answers were of value to you, please upvote or Accept for feedback to the people trying to help you.

Comment: Cut your innodb_buffer_pool_size to 2G until you can be stable and acquire more RAM.

Comment: @samad Have you removed the 3 lines from your configuration listed in my answer of Dec 4, 20 at 11:50?  Are you still failing every few hours?

Comment: @wilson-hauk , Thanks for your reply but the problem is not solved

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @wilson-hauk, Thanks for your reply but I cant Send this information

Comment: Assistance will be limited to available data.  Have a GREAT 2021.